# ffmpeg copying audio codec type while concating videos

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using the following commands:

```
ffmpeg -i data/staging/0.mkv -i data/staging/1.mkv -map 0 -filter_complex concat=n=2:v=1:a=2 -threads 8.0 data/staging/concat.mkv -y -loglevel error
```

To combine 2 videos with 2 audio streams and -map 0 is used to maintain various other streams including multiple subs etc.

But the audio going in AAC and coming out the concat end seems to be voris? I am not sure why this occurs. Is there a way to maintain this?

The codecs for all input clips will be identical, ad they are split from the same video previously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you do not tell `ffmpeg` which encoder you want to use it will choose a default encoder.
- The default encoder depends on how your `ffmpeg` was configured. In your case the default encoder for MKV is libvorbis.
- You can see the defaults with `ffmpeg -h muxer=matroska`.
- Filtering requires re-encoding, so it is not possible to [stream copy](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) (like a copy and paste) the audio with `-c:a copy`.
- You will have to manually provide the desired encoder name: `-c:a aac`.

Comment: Nice, thanks for the info. Am I able to add name for each audio stream? I am doing this in python, I can look up streams and chain the commands.

Comment: *"Am I able to add name for each audio stream?* Do you mean an encoder name? Or a metadata title?

Comment: I mean encoder. I guess its possible for there to be different codecs for different audio streams? I can look up each from streams data and add flags to concat? If not, I can just use 1 generic encoder.. Right now the audio in the final output file is choppy which is annoying..

Comment: @ScipioAfricanus `-c:a aac` will make all audio AAC. If you want audio #0 to be AAC and audio #1 to be MP3: `-c:a:0 aac -c:a:1 libmp3lame`.

Comment: brilliant thank you, presumably I can follow the same logic with video.

Comment: @ScipioAfricanus Yes, `-c:v libx264` for all, or `-c:v:0 libx264 -c:v:1 libvpx-vp9`, etc.